# Graphql in Shopify: getting order with "order_name" instead of id

Tags: graphql, shopify

Let's say I have a query in Shopify where I want to retrieve an order, but not by id, but by order_name. With the rest API, this is perfectly possible. How do I do that in graphql?

The request for Shopify looks like that:

```
    {
       order(id: "") {
         closed
       }
    }
```

Comment: it is not possible with GraphQL to retrieve an order. And also it is not possible to filter orders with order name since the name is not in filterable params in orders query.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by query:"order_name", but not sure how shopify priortizes the fields, so be careful